# How to keep node app alive on digital ocean through ssh

Tags: linux, node.js, digital-ocean

I'm new to digital ocean (I've only used heroku in the past). I have a basic node app that I've setup on my droplet/server. I ssh in, run npm start, and my app runs. all is good. However, if I end my ssh connection, my app dies (broken pipe).

How can I start my app and not require my ssh connection to always be alive in order for my app to be running?

(I'm running Ubuntu node v4.4.0 on 14.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should launch your Node process with a process supervisor like [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) in order to ensure it stays running if something happens.

The quick and dirty approach is to background your app with something like:

```
node app.js &
```

Yet that's very brittle. If the process has an error it will die and not restart.

You may also want to add `pm2` to your `crontab` under `@reboot` to kick it off when the system gets restarted.

Comment: awesome thanks. is that a typo where you have `node app.js &`? I have it running well now with pm2, eg `pm2 start server.js`

Comment: At the very least you'll probably need to prepend `nohup ` to that command.

Comment: @ben The `&` character in the shell at the end means "run in background". This doesn't guarantee it stays running, or even starts up properly, but it means it's detached from the shell. `pm2` is much better since it saves logs for you and gives you a status report.